# Getting "about:" as event.origin in ie/edge when communicating between two children iframe via postmessage

Tags: javascript

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="iframe" src="inner.html"></iframe>
    <iframe id="iframe2">


    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" id="val"/>
    <input type="button" id="button" onclick="callPostMessage();" />

    <p><b>Main Window </b></p>

    <label id="label"></label>

    </body>
    </html>
    </iframe>

    <script>
    var script = document.createElement('script'); 
    script.src = "myjs.js";
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    document.getElementById('iframe2').contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script); 
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

frame1.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
    window.onload = function () {
        initilizeMarsEventListener();
    };

    function initilizeMarsEventListener() {
        console.log('In initilizeMarsEventListener');
        if (window.addEventListener) {
            window.addEventListener("message", receiveDataFromXYZDomain, false);
        }
        else {
            window.attachEvent("onmessage", receiveDataFromXYZDomain);
        }
    }

    function receiveDataFromXYZDomain(evt) {

        var val = document.getElementById("label");
        val.innerHTML = evt.data;


    }

    function sendAuthTokenToCRMDomain() {
        console.log('In sendAuthTokenToXYZDomain' );

        top.window.postMessage(val.value, "*");
    }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <p><b>Iframe </b></p>
        <input type="text" id="val" />
        <input type="button" id="button" onclick="sendAuthTokenToXYZDomain();" />
        <label id="label"></label>
    </body>


</html>
```

myjs.js

```
    window.addEventListener("message",
      function (e) {
        //if (e.origin !== 'http://localhost:2345') { alert("Wrong origin " + e.origin); return; }
        //alert("Value from Iframe" + e.data);
        var val = document.getElementById("label");
        alert(e.data);
        val.innerHTML = e.data;
      },
      false);

    function callPostMessage() {
        debugger;
        //var val = document.getElementById("val");
        val = { name : "alex"};
        var iframeWin = window.parent.document.getElementById("iframe");
        var iframeContent = iframeWin.contentWindow;
        window.setTimeout(function() {
    iframeContent.postMessage(val, "*"); 
  }, 0);

    }


(function (){
    var myButton = document.createElement('button');
    myButton.setAttribute("text","callPostMessage");
    myButton.setAttribute("onclick","callPostMessage()");
    window.parent.document.getElementById("iframe2").contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(myButton); 



})("addControl", window);
```

on clicking the button in frame 2 postmessage method is called and received by frame 1 in receiveDataFromXYZDomain. However the evt.origin comes out to be "about:" in ie/edge (working fine in chrome/firefox).